# Recycleview wrap_content issue

Tags: android

I am facing this weird issue where my Recycleview is wrap_content in height but it is taking full height of screen whereas my content is only occupying half the screen space.
I read it that this was a bug and it is fixed in 23.2.1. I am using :-

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
```

In the xml also, i have not added anything specific :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycleview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_circular_progress_bar" />
</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see from the image my content is only half, the round white part and the below red part is extra. How to remove this ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently faced the same issue true it's a bug ;
i solved it with simple hack :
place any linear layout or any view just below recyclerview and set it to invisible this will help recycler to adapt to wrapping height measurement.

Second solution to it is making custom linear layout and using this in recyclerview.setlayoutmanager